# PHP: Embed debugging info in output?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

Is there an easy way to get PHP to output a stack trace in an HTML comment everwhere it produces output? I am using xdebug, but being able to search through a massive dump would be helpful when I am placing breakpoints in the wrong place.

> Hell is other people's code

Comment: No. But you could wrap echo/print calls to include such a thing. `function myecho($arg) { var_dump(...); echo $arg; }`.

Comment: It's the echos that I didn't write that worry me. There are hundreds of them. Maybe thousands.

Comment: You'd have to patch the PHP interpreter to enable such a thing. There's no way to override a built-in function this way. Well, there was a PHP module that fiddled around in the guts of PHP at runtime to accomplish it, but I don't think it's available anymore because it was highly dangerous to muck around like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No direct way exists.

Indirectly, you may include a DIV element in the target page:

```
<div id="debugInfo">
 ...
</div>
```

Fill the DIV with the **debug info** you'd like to know.

Use CSS and JavaScript reduce the size of the `DIV` to e.g. 20 x 10 px by default.

Using an `onmousedown` event, maximize the `DIV` element. On the next `onmousedown` event, reduce the size again.

In other words: Each click on the `DIV` element toggles its size.

Comment: Javascript? CSS? I would settle for stack traces interleaved with PHP's output. No need for a UI. But I think you are right, there is no easy way, which answers my original question.